# ¿Como puedo modificar este codigo Java para tomar la imagen de un imageView y no de la galeria? Android

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas, android-drawerlayout

Este codigo es parte de un codigo fuente que sirve para editar fotos, pero yo quiero modificarlo para quitar la funcion que hace que tome las fotos desde la galeria y tome cualquier foto que yo ponga en un ImageView.

Me ayudaria mucho que pudieran ayudarme , gracias!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//declaring necesary variables
public static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA = 100,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE=1;
public static final String ALLOW_KEY = "ALLOWED";
public static final String CAMERA_PREF = "camera_pref";
public static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORE = 99;
public static final String STORE_PREF = "store_pref";
public static String mCurrentPhotoPath;
public final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE =20;
public Uri pickedImage;

ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

   
    checkPermG();

    FloatingActionButton addFab = findViewById(R.id.addFab);
    addFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String items[] = {"Capture Image from Camera","Choose Image from Gallery","Cancel"};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert);
            builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if(items[i].equals("Capture Image from Camera")){checkPermC();}
                    else if(items[i].equals("Choose Image from Gallery")){galleryIntent();}
                    else{dialogInterface.dismiss();}
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });
}

public static void saveToPreferences(Context context, String key, Boolean allowed){
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(CAMERA_PREF,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putBoolean(key,allowed);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}

public static boolean getFromPref(Context context,String key){
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(CAMERA_PREF,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return (myPrefs.getBoolean(key,false));
}

private void showAlert(){

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("App needs to access the Camera!");
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "DON'T ALLOW", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "ALLOW", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();


}

private void showSettingsAlert(){

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("App needs to access the Camera.");
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "DON'T ALLOW", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "ALLOW", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();

        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[],int[] grantResults){

    switch (requestCode){
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA:
            for(int i=0,len=permissions.length;i<len;i++){
                String permission = permissions[i];
                if(grantResults[i]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                    boolean showRationale = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,permission);
                    if(showRationale){showAlert();}
                    else if(!showRationale){
                        // user denied flagging NEVER ASK AGAIN
                        // you can either enable some fall back,
                        // disable features of your app
                        // or open another dialog explaining
                        // again the permission and directing to
                        // the app setting
                        saveToPreferences(MainActivity.this,ALLOW_KEY,true);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORE:
            for(int i=0,len=permissions.length;i<len;i++){
                String permission = permissions[i];
                if(grantResults[i]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                    boolean showRationale = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,permission);
                    if(showRationale){showAlert();}
                    else if(!showRationale){
                        // user denied flagging NEVER ASK AGAIN
                        // you can either enable some fall back,
                        // disable features of your app
                        // or open another dialog explaining
                        // again the permission and directing to
                        // the app setting
                        saveToPreferencesG(MainActivity.this,ALLOW_KEY,true);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}


protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
}

//function to open camera
private void openCamera(){
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

    if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){

        File photoFile = null;
        try{
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.d("","Couldn't create File");}

        if(photoFile != null){
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.example.android.photo_editor_fileprovider",photoFile);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }

    }



}

//function called on getting image either from camera or gallery. Gets file path and starts activity to diplay image
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int ResultCode,Intent data){

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && ResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

        Intent i = new Intent(this,Image_Display_Activity.class);
        int H = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
        int W = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
        i.putExtra("height",H);
        i.putExtra("width",W);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && ResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){


        pickedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage,filePath,null,null,null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Image_Display_Activity.class);
        int H = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
        int W = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
        i.putExtra("height",H);
        i.putExtra("width",W);
        startActivity(i);

    }

}

//function to create a file to store the image. It creates new file name with time stamp
private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_"+timeStamp+"_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);

    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

//check if app has permission to open camera. open if yes
public void checkPermC(){

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(getFromPref(this,ALLOW_KEY)){showSettingsAlert();}
        else if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //should we show an explanation?
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){showAlert();}
            else {
                //no explanation needed, we can request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
        }
    }
    else {openCamera(); }

}

//function to open gallery to pick image
public void galleryIntent(){

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i,RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

}

//function to check if app has access to storage
public void checkPermG(){

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(getFromPrefG(this,ALLOW_KEY)){showSettingsAlertG();}
        else if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //should we show an explanation?
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){showAlertG();}
            else {
                //no explanation needed, we can request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORE);
            }
        }
    }

}

public static boolean getFromPrefG(Context context, String key){
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(STORE_PREF,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return (myPrefs.getBoolean(key,false));
}

public static void saveToPreferencesG(Context context,String key,Boolean allowed){
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(STORE_PREF,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putBoolean(key,allowed);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}

private void showAlertG(){

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("App needs to access storage!");
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "DON'T ALLOW", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "ALLOW", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORE);
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();


}

private void showSettingsAlertG(){

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("App needs to access storage!.");
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "DON'T ALLOW", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "ALLOW", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();

        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}

}
```

**IGNOREN ESTO** is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: El codigo que muestra es para tomar foto de galeria o camara creo, no hay nada para modificar ahi , creo que lo que buscas esta en el Image_Display_Activity. En activity result esta el currentphotopath esa es tu pista.

Comment: alguna sugerencia de que puedo hacer?

Comment: ir a Image_Display_Activity y modificar su codigo algun lado recibe un bitmap y lo pone al imgeview preview, ahi cambias el bitmap por el bitmap de tu imageview seleccionado.

Comment: pero de igual manera me va a pedir que seleccione una imagen al inicio